# How to center icons in bottom launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

Already have launcher at the bottom and would like to center icons.

Comment: Waiting an answer also. If someone have an idea, please, give it.

Comment: Surprised there are no answers yet.. Well at least we could move the launcher to the bottom!

Comment: Does it have to be the Unity launcher, or could it be another program that works that way?

Comment: Yes, that's because Unity Launcher is not a dock. It is a Launcher and way different from a dock. This is what Canonical has to say. You will have to use Cairo Dock or Plank to get the desired Dock. So, there is no native way for achieving it.

Comment: In Ubuntu 17.10, the extension is literally called "Ubuntu Dock."  Given that one of Ubuntu Dock's options is to position the dock at the bottom of the screen, it would seem like an obvious derivative option (or even default behavior) to center the icons in that position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height false
```

This will adjust the size of the dock so it doesn't take up more space than actually needed for the icons.

Comment: Is there any way to center only icons and not the whole dock?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use cario dock, it sucks, it looks horrible on my mac OS mod

I suggest plank

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install plank
```

Ubuntu 16.04-18.04

Answer (score 0):

You can install Cairo Dock. This will put your icons in the center as well as shrink your unity launcher.
Run these commands in the terminal to install cairo dock:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins
```

Comment: Well, that uses alternative launcher, but unfortunately that's not a solution for Unity's native one

Answer (score -1):

You could also just head to the Ubuntu Software Centre and search Cairo Dock and install it.

It's a wonderful launcher that allows users to customise the way their dock looks as well as the various functions of clicking, right-clicking, and middle-clicking on the launcher icons. The icons are customisable, as well.

When you install it, the launcher appears in the bottom centre of the screen (when you hover near the bottom-centre) with some default icons that you can remove/edit, if you like, as well as further instructions on how to use Cairo-Dock.

Cairo-Dock behaves much like the OSX dock does in Macs.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you please [edit] your question to add more information about how to install Cairo Dock, and how it would solve OP's problem? In its current state, this answer is more of a comment and doesn't provide much information.